# Impossible to post special character into dialogflow query

Tags: json, angular, http, utf-8, dialogflow-es

I'm working on a dialgflow V1 bot.
I'm really inspired by this repository : https://github.com/mlabouardy/dialogflow-angular5

I have an issue in my dialogflow service.
I can't post query with special characters.

here is my diaogflow service working but when i pass my query it is code to utf-8 which broke dialogflow :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx'
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class DialogflowService {

  private baseURL: string = "https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20170712";
  private token: string = environment.dialogFlowToken;

  constructor(private http: Http){}

  public getResponse(query: string){
    let data = {
      query : query,
      lang: 'fr',
      sessionId: '12345'
    }

    return this.http
      .post(`${this.baseURL}`, data, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
      .map(res => {
        return res.json()
      })
  }

  public getHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.token}`);
    return headers;
  }
}
```

I tried to use :

```
  encode_utf8(s) {
    return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
  }

  decode_utf8(s) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
  }
```

But it didn't work

Do you have a suggestion ?
Thanks a lot.
Romain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to force it with additional header and see if that works.

{'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

Comment: Wonderful thanks a lot !


  public getHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.token}` );
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' );
    return headers;
  }

It worked like a charm !

Comment: You welcome, a good tip would be always check your header request in the browser network. That way you make sure it contains the right headers.